# How to read the the System class API

Tags: java, api, system

I'm trying to understand how the System class works.

When I go to the API, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html), I see a field summary and method summary. I understand the method summary to be a list of all the methods. But what is the Field Summary?

And what are err, in, out, referring to?

Comment: Why are you looking at the 1.4.2 docs?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Comment: If you understand the method summary to he a list of all the methods, surely you can understand the field summary to be a list of all the fields? What's the question here?

Comment: I never saw a list of fields in any other API class, I wasn't sure what they were. The answer seems obvious now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nambari answered the first part of your question, here is the last part:

From the docs you linked from:

```
Field Summary
static PrintStream  err 
          The "standard" error output stream.
static InputStream  in 
          The "standard" input stream.
static PrintStream  out 
      The "standard" output stream.
```

err is where errors go, this can be redirected to file, console or wherever.

in is the input stream, be it file, keyboard, stream etc

out is the output, most often console or GUI based.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I should have copied that in.

Answer (score 1):

**Field summary** means static variables of that class/interface.

For example, **out** is static variable inside System class which will be initiated on System class load and can be accessed using syntax `System.out`.

NOTE: It is always better to refer correct version of documentation. 1.4.2 is little old.

Answer (score 1):

Java is opensource - if you have doubts you can always have a look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/System.java) to have a better idea of how things are designed

If you download the full source, you can even directly jump to the source code of any function from eclipse!